# Is $[Q \quad Y+YA^T; Y+AY \quad Y]>0$ if $Q>0$ and $Y>0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $Y>0$ and $Q>0$ (positive definite) $n\times n$ real matrix, if $A$ ($n\times n$) is an invertible matrix.

Then can we show that
$$
T=\pmatrix{Q & Y + YA^T\\ Y + AY & Y}>0?
$$

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: If you apply Schur complement lemma and congruence transformation by inv(Y), I get $\alpha Y^{-1}-(I+A^T)Y^{-1}(I+A)>0$ as $Y^{-1}$ is positive definite, I thought I can scale alpha too big such that the matrix T is always positive definite.

Comment: I have modified the LMI slightly, can someone please comment, is it feasible now ?

Comment: It certainly isn't always positive definite. E.g. consider the scalar case with $A$ being sufficiently large.

Comment: I have checked for A=1000000000000, it is not positive definite, as per the results of MATLAB. But intuitively I am not able to understand how this is happening, would you please elaborate in simple words.